# Visual Studio 2015 Community and 2013 Express side by side install not working

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I currently have VS 2013 express installed and want to additionally install VS 2015 Community Edition (Win 8.1).

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms246609.aspx this should work I think but when running the VS 2015 Community Edition installer the install location chooser is greyed out and points to my VS 2013 Express edition install, which it will overwrite when executing it (I've tried).

How can I point the VS 2015 installer to another location ?

Comment: It worked by doing it the other way round, uninstalling VS 2013, installing VS 2015 then installing VS 2013 again I could choose a different location for it in the installer. So this is solved (with a 'workaround').