# Unable to Install Visual Studio 2013 on Computer with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have a Windows 8.1 computer with Visual Studio Community 2015 installed and no other version of Visual Studio. I want to install Visual Studio Community 2013 because this is required to use C++ with Unreal Engine 4. But I get
[this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsAaR.png) when I try to install.

[image: this error message]

So I restarted my computer, and the same error message still shows up. I have tried installing from an executable from the Visual Studio webpage, and from a button in Unreal Engine 4 that opens the Visual Studio 2013 installer. What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at the logs?

Comment: Here's the log file: [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7AAE9EA4B5726552!7984&authkey=!AHvmUfoja5E6Bcs&ithint=file%2clog). I don't understand what it means, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From memory, you're supposed to be able to install multiple versions of visual studio, provided you install them chronologically.

Make a backup.
Then try uninstalling VS 2015. Then installing VS 2013, then re-installing VS 2015.

Better yet, do this in a virtual machine.
 - Additionally; A virtual machine will allow you to install VS 2013 in isolation, so that you won't need to uninstall VS 2015.

Comment: And indeed - this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800320/visual-studio-2015-community-and-2013-express-side-by-side-install-not-working?rq=1 (as it turns out)

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to solve the issue without uninstalling VS 2015. What kind of backup were you thinking I should do?

Comment: @ZaneHintzman: Always have a backup ready in case your HDD goes bad. (And it will), or the software runs amock (which it might).  For both of those scenarios, consider how you will get back to a productive setup again, quickly. Regarding solving the issue without uninstalling VS 2015...  I'll update the answer with a possible answer.

Comment: Now I'm trying to uninstall Visual Studio 2015 through the Control Panel, but it also gives the error "Setup Blocked" with "The computer needs to be restarted..." Here's the log file for this issue: [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7AAE9EA4B5726552!7990&authkey=!AINNWi5TtzUlIxo&ithint=file%2clog). I heard that this is a problem in Windows 8.1 because it only hibernates when I reset, so I tried this suggestion: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346692/microsoft-visual-studio-setup-blocked). But that didn't work either. Does that mean I did it wrong, or what?

Comment: @ZaneHintzman: At risk of sounding condescending, learn how to reboot your computer.

Comment: Is not being able to restart the real problem here? Is there anything else in the log file that would indicate the problem? I don't know what's relevant in the file.

Comment: I finally solved the problem. I downloaded the latest installer for Visual Studio 2015 to see if it could repair the installation. The same error appeared at first, but I turned off hibernation again through the Command Line, reset the computer while the error window was still open, and then ran the installer again. From there, I uninstalled VS 2015, which then allowed me to install VS 2013. I did try turning off hibernation and resetting when the message displayed after trying to uninstall VS 2015 from the Control Panel. But it didn't work back then for some reason.